# Is there a standard e-commerce database schema to apply the discounts/taxes/gift vouchers to products?

Tags: database, e-commerce

A good and flexible database schema illustrating e-commerce products and their rates management is required.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I agree with Chris Roberts, [OSCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/community/contributions,3853/page,23) is a good place to start as well as [DatabaseAnswers.org](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/index.htm).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've been looking for this, the OsCommerce link is great schema to start with, thanks Pal

Comment: These are both dead links in 2022, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are many examples about - try looking at some open source shopping cart tools.

As a general point, though, I think there are so many ways that a product pricing and discount / gift voucher system *could* work that finding a database schema that works for *every* possibility is unlikely!

Perhaps you can save yourself some heartache by refining the requirements a little?